# How can I simplify adding columns with certain values to my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe (more than 900000 rows) and want to add some columns depending on the first column (Timestamp with date and time). My code works, but I guess it's far too complicated and slow. I'm a beginner so help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
df['seconds_midnight'] = 0
df['weekday'] = 0
df['month'] = 0

def date_to_new_columns(date_var, i):
    sec_after_midnight = dt.timedelta(hours=date_var.hour, minutes=date_var.minute, seconds=date_var.second).total_seconds()
    weekday = dt.date.isoweekday(date_var)
    month1 = date_var.month
    df.iloc[i, 24] = sec_after_midnight
    df.iloc[i, 25] = weekday
    df.iloc[i, 26] = month1
    return


for i in range(0, 903308):
    date_to_new_columns(df.timestamp.iloc[i], i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason this is slow is the for loop processing each row individually. One thing that makes pandas so nice is that you can quickly process whole columns/dataframes in one operation.

So create all the rows for each new column at the same time:

```
def date_to_new_columns(df):
    df['sec_after_midnight'] = (df.timestamp - df.timestamp.dt.normalize()).dt.seconds
    df['weekday'] = df.timestamp.dt.day_name
    df['month1'] = df.timestamp.dt.month
    return
```

Note that the dt.day_name method is called dt.weekday_name prior to pandas version 0.23.0.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is a datetime64/Timestamp column you can use the [.dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dt-accessor):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2019-01-23', periods=3), columns=['date'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
        date
0 2019-01-23
1 2019-01-24
2 2019-01-25

In [13]: df.date - df.date.dt.normalize()  # timedelta since midnight
Out[13]:
0   0 days
1   0 days
2   0 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [14]: (df.date - df.date.dt.normalize()).dt.seconds  # seconds since midnight
Out[14]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
Name: date, dtype: int64

In [15]: df.date.dt.day_name()
Out[15]:
0    Wednesday
1     Thursday
2       Friday
Name: date, dtype: object

In [16]: df.date.dt.month_name()
Out[16]:
0    January
1    January
2    January
Name: date, dtype: object
```